# pandas set values of level of multiindex giving NaN

Tags: pandas

I want to set one level of a multiindex dataframe. in what I did, pandas writes NaNs and I cannot work around it. This is the code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0,30,1).reshape(3,10))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100,130,1).reshape(3,10))

df.columns = list("abcdefghij")
df2.columns = list("abcdefghij")
df = df.groupby(["a", "b", "c"]).agg("sum")
df2 = df2.groupby(["a", "b", "c"]).agg("sum")

df.loc[slice(0,0),slice(1,1),slice(2,2), :] = df2.loc[slice(100,100),slice(101,101),slice(102,102), :]
print(df)
```

if you run this, the row that is being set turns into Nans, despite being full of numbers originally. can this be worked around somewhat?

Comment: The issue is not the MultiIndex, it's just that your Indexes are not aligned. Use `df.loc[slice(0,0),slice(1,1),slice(2,2), :] = df2.loc[slice(100,100),slice(101,101),slice(102,102), :].to_numpy()`. Also, you're not slicing one **level** but rather one row on all levels. Your slices are also useless, your command is equivalent to `df.loc[(0, 1, 2), :] = df2.loc[(100, 101, 102), :]`

Comment: thanks a lot. tried various things. this works.

Comment: the odd slicing is because I used get_level_values before to directly take the row and wanted to to see if get_level_values is the problem.